# номер символа в ASCII

Tags: java

у меня имеется символ, например - 'a'. нужен способ узнать его код в таблице. заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Первое в google.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458564/convert-character-to-ascii-numeric-value-in-java)

Умение пользоваться данным поисковиком поможет Вам в дальнейшем.

```
char character = 'a';    
int ascii = (int) character; // 97
```